# W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository... doesn't support architecture '1386'

Tags: updates, repository

I've recently started having difficulty with the Software Updater. When I try to run it, I get the message:

`Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection.`

My connection is working fine, so I'm sure it must be something else. Below is the output from Details input as code, because it was the only way  I could find that it would allow me to include it.

```
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386', 
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirror.steadfast.net/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386', 
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.3/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386', 
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386',
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.,
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386', 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
```

Running the following commands produced no output.

```
grep -i 1386 /etc/apt/sources.list
grep -i 1386 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is set up with an incorrect architecture type.

In `terminal`...

Lets see what we have now...

```
sudo dpkg --print-architecture
    # could show amd64
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures # note the ending s
    # could show 1386 <-- this is the bad one
```

Lets fix the problem...

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386 # delete the bad one
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 # add a good one
```

**Update #1:**

The error `E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/dists/xenial` is because no xenial repository exists.

In `terminal`...

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
grep -i miro-releases *.list
    # note the filename that is returned
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/{enter found filename here}
    # comment out the deb lines by placing a # at the beginning of the lines
    # save the file and quit gedit
```

Comment: I've successfully executed all the commands. Software Updater is still failing to download the repository information.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of: `grep -i 1386 /etc/apt/sources.list` and `grep -i 1386 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Also, show me the output of the first two commands in my answer.

Comment: I tried running those commands in terminal, but it didn't generate any output. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @AllanMcPherson that's actually good. As I asked, show me the output of the first two commands in my answer. "Lets see what we have now".

Comment: @heynneam Thank you for your help. When I first ran those commands, print-architecture gave amd64 and print-foreign-architectures gave 1386 and i386. After having run the commands you gave to fix that, they give amd64 and i386 as output.

Comment: I think I wasn't fully awake last time I tried to run grep. This time it returned the appropriate filename. I commented out the offending line, and Software Updater is working now. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @AllanMcPherson glad it all worked out! Thanks for the update.